# Async function not returning resolve to variable/const

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've ben working on making a simple web scraper to get a deeper understanding of using async/await and promise/resolve functionality. I'm having an issue with an async/await function not returning my resolve properly. I'm able to console.log the complete dataset within the function, right before the return resolve, but I'm not able to assign a constant and call the function outside the scope of the function itself, and console.log that data (it's returned as undefined).

This is the function that is supposed to return the dataset i'm scraping for. The saleHeaders are being pulled successfully, because I'm able to scrape for the content and assign to it's respective constant. When using the console.log that's commented out below, I get the complete dataset output.

```
async function getInnerPosts(saleHeaders) {
  await Promise.all(saleHeaders.map(async (job) => {
    const dataSet = [];
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      request(job.fullURL, (err, res, html) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $('.result-info').each((index, element) => {
            const postTitle     = $(element).children(".result-title").text();
            const postDate      = $(element).children(".result-date").attr('title');
            const postLink      = $(element).children("a").attr('href');
            const postPrice     = $(element).children(".result-meta").children(".result-price").text();
            const postLocation  = $(element).children(".result-meta").children(".result-hood").text().replace(/[{()}]/g, '');
            // gather data to one const
            const fetchedData   = { postTitle, postDate, postLink, postPrice, postLocation };
            dataSet.push(fetchedData);
            // console.log(dataSet);
        });
        return resolve(dataSet);
      });
    });
  }));
}
```

But when I try to run the function, assigning it to a constant, and then attempt to log that constant, I'm getting undefined without any warning/errors being thrown. I've attempted to re-structure the returning of the dataset and re-writing the complete function from scratch to make sure I didn't miss some minor mistake, but no luck.

```
async function scrapeData() {
    const saleHeaders = await getForSaleHeader();
    // Loop through the categories and pull the inner-data from the posts page
    const innerPosts = await getInnerPosts(saleHeaders);
    console.log(innerPosts);
}
```

This is the time, and output i'm receiving when running the above-mentioned code sample:

```
undefined

real    0m31.272s
user    0m33.594s
sys 0m0.322s
```

*EDIT*
I am calling the whole script to run as well:

```
// run the script
scrapeData();
```

Comment: you just need to `return await Promise.all(...)`, you missed the `return`

Comment: Where exactly did I miss the return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you're mixing Promises with `async`/`await`. Remember that if a function returns a Promise (e.g. `return new Promise` or `return Promise.all`), then it *should not* be `async`.

A smaller but just as significant problem is that `getInnerPosts` doesn't return anything. It begins with `await Promise.all(...)`. It should begin with `return Promise.all(...)`. Without a `return` there, `getInnerPosts` returns `undefined`, so the function that calls it is essentially just doing `await undefined`, which immediately resolves to `undefined`.

Let's break this down step by step. First, get most of this code out of the way by pulling the cheerio selector code into its own function:

```
function getData(element) {
  const $el = $(element);
  return {
    postTitle: $el.children('.result-title').text(),
    postDate: $el.children('.result-date').attr('title'),
    postLink: $el.children('a').attr('href'),
    postPrice: $el.children('.result-meta > .result-price').text(),
    postLocation: $el.children('.result-meta > .result-hood').text().replace(/[{()}]/g, ''),
  };
}
```

Next, get rid of the `async`/`await`s and add a `return` before `Promise.all`:

```
function getInnerPosts(saleHeaders) {
  return Promise.all(saleHeaders.map(job => {
    const dataSet = [];
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      request(job.fullURL, (err, res, html) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $('.result-info').each((index, element) => dataSet.push(getData(element)));
        resolve(dataSet);
      });
    });
  }));
}
```

This should be sufficient to make your code work as expected. However, that pyramid structure is not very easy to read. Let's see if we can improve it.

First, you can wrap your call to `request` in a function that returns a Promise (alternatively you could use e.g. [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native)). Having done that, you can make the callback you pass to `saleHeaders.map` an `async` function and use `await pRequest(...)` inside. Finally, you can eliminate `dataSet` entirely by using cheerio's `map` instead of calling `push` inside an `each` loop. The end result looks like this:

```
function pRequest(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    request(url, (err, res, html) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(html)));
}

function getInnerPosts(saleHeaders) {
  return Promise.all(saleHeaders.map(async job => {
    const html = await pRequest(job.fullURL);
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    return $('.result-info').map((index, element) => getData(element)));
  }));
}
```

---

In reply to your comment:

> Still trying to wrap my head around the difference between async/await and promises.

Understanding the difference—or, more importantly, the relationship—between `async`/`await` and promises is not trivial. It requires three or four layers of understanding. You need to understand how asynchronous callbacks (e.g. the function you pass to `request` or `setTimeout`) work in JS, then you need to understand how promises relate to callbacks, and finally how `async`/`await` relates to promises. It's a tough nut to crack, and I think most people pick it up just through experience.

If I have any advice, it's to slow down. Think about each part of your code and what it's actually doing. When you write this:

```
request(url, (err, res, body) => { /* … */ });
```

…what happens to that second argument (the callback) inside the `request` function?

When you write this:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => { /* … */ })
  .catch (err => { /* … */ });
```

…what does `fetch(url)` return, and what is `then`? Why can you write this instead (in an `async` function)?

```
try {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  // …
} catch (err) {
  // …
}
```

Will it behave the same way, or are there differences?

Slow down and think about what you're writing. Don't add an `await` unless you know why you're doing it. Don't add a `new Promise` unless you know why you're doing it.

And finally, break your code up into smaller functions. It's easy to lose track of where you need to `return` or where you want an `await` when your function has a `Promise.all`, a `new Promise`, and three nested callbacks. It's much easier to tell if a function could be `async` if it's only 2–3 lines long.

> Is there any advantage of using one over the other?

IMO the main advantage of `async`/`await` is readability. Promise constructors and nested `then`/`catch` callbacks *work*, but they tend to obscure the intent of your code. `async`/`await` makes your code read more like normal synchronous code (not to mention "await" is an English word that's already familiar) which makes it easier to divine the intent. Of course, you still need Promises. `await` makes a function effectively pause, but sometimes there's only one thing you want to defer while the rest of the function executes, so you need `then`. And there's no replacement for `Promise.all`

Comment: Wow, great! Thank you for explaining it so thoroughly, this is exactly what I was looking for. Also, appreciate the feedback on improving the code as well. Still trying to wrap my head around the difference between async/await and promises. Is there any advantage of using one over the other?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some more information re: your comment. It's nothing like comprehensive, though, as this isn't really the right venue for it, but I hope it's helpful.

Comment: "Immediately resolves to undefined" is wrong. It does resolve to undefined, but definitely not "immediately".

Comment: Plus, any function that returns a promise is not required to be `async` so as to be usefully `await`-able. But adding an `async` doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your return statement only returns inside the map function (map has a return statement but the function itself does not!

Comment: I tried nesting the return outside the scope of the map function, and it didn't do anything differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getInnerPosts(saleHeaders) {
  // here
  return await Promise.all(saleHeaders.map(async (job) => {
    const dataSet = [];
    return new Promise(resolve => {
```

You have to return it because you want to further use the value outside the function.

```
const innerPosts = await getInnerPosts(saleHeaders);
```

If you don't, where do you think the value of `innerPosts` comes from? It's returned from the `getInnerPosts`!

Comment: Okay, that seems to have done the trick and it's returning now as it should. How though? I don't quite understand having to return the await?

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 man I didn't mean to post an "answer" answer, if comment has correct format, i'd comment. Now suddenly I'm obligated to explain it or delete it. I don't like this feeling.

Comment: I understand that, was just wondering if you could shed any more light as to why that would have been the deciding factor for the return. Thanks for your help, I was able to get it working with your advice.

Comment: @OlegKontsograda I'd recommend you to google some serious explanation on async-await. Also if you're interested to know the internal work of async-await, you'll need to understand *generator*, then go check [this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=async%20function%20foobar()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20await%20Promise.all(%5BPromise.resolve(1)%5D)%0D%0A%7D). This is how the magic happen

Comment: @OlegKontsograda sorry I might sound harsh, but it's just impossible to explain it all here. This path I point out is worth you time investigating, if you're serious about "get a deeper understanding of using async/await". The link about, those generated code, that's the deepest you can get, if you understand that gimmick, there's no magic.